# How to refresh access token received with Azure authentication?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I have a usual (tutorial-like) piece of code in Azure Service App. The HomeController is initialized as:

```
public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient, ITokenAcquisition tokenAcquisition)
{
    var task = Task.Run(async () => await m_tokenAcquisition.GetAuthenticationResultForUserAsync(new[] { "some.allowed.scope" }));
    var context = task.Result;
    var accessToken = context.AccessToken;
    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("FeatureFlag", "00000004");
    var newGraphClient = new GraphServiceClient(client);
}
```

The access token is good to go for 'GraphServiceClient'.

There is no use for the access token after it expires which happens in an hour or so. But the service needs to do periodic work on Azure account without bothering the user.

The main question is how should I proceed to prevent the user from frequent logins?

Comment: The usual way to support this is by the use of "refresh tokens", which enable the application to refresh the access token. But it appears that the ITokenAcquisition interface handles this for you, according to this issue: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/issues/945

Comment: When using ITokenAcquisition I obtain the token. It expected to expire in 60-75 minutes. 
How should I obtain another token without asking a user to re-login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To access the refreshed token without asking users to login.

You need to customize the code for refreshing the token in application with the timer by checking the token expiry before it happens or by adding a listener for the token expiry event.

```
_timer = new Timer(TokenRefresh, null, _expiresIn * 1000 - 60000, Timeout.Infinite);


   using (var client = new HttpClient())
               {
                   var response = await client.PostAsync("https://authserver.com/token", new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
                   {
                   new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grantType", "tokenRefresh"),
                   new KeyValuePair<string, string>("tokenRefresh", _tokenRefresh)
               }));
                   var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
   
                   var json = JObject.Parse(responseContent);
                   _accessToken = (string)json["accessToken"];
                   _tokenRefresh = (string)json["tokenRefresh"];
                   _expiresIn = (int)json["expiresIn"];
                   //Expires in 1 hrs (3600)
               }
   
               _timer.Change(_expiresIn * 1000 - 60000, Timeout.Infinite);
```

You need to log into the application.

And the application has to send the login credentials to an authentication serverand has to verify them. And  then returns an access token, refresh token.
Now you have the access token and refresh token securely on the client side.

When the access token expires, the application uses the refresh token to request a new access token from the authentication server.
The authentication server checks the refresh token and returns a new access token.

You need to customize the code for refreshing the token in application with the timer by checking the token expiry before it happens or by adding a listener for the token expiry event or delegate

As the refresh token has a shortlife, you need to use the new refresh token obtained from the token refresh process to get new access token again.

For Safety the refresh token and access token have to be stored securely and encrypted.

References taken from

[Token Requests](https://developers.home.google.com/cloud-to-cloud/project/authorization)

[Github Code](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/blob/fd8fa2d5bed28dc38cdd869857258fea1f859935/source/Core/Services/Default/DefaultRefreshTokenService.cs#L57)